# Querying multiple tables and returning 1 compiled result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have two tables

```
Table 1
--------
price
product
san
code

Table 2
-------
price
```

Can I say something like, select price from table1 and select price from table2 and then return the results? So if table 1 had 3 records and table 2 had 5 records, it would return 8 records?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `union all` as below

```
select price
from tabel1
union all
select price
from tabel2
```

Comment: nice! so if i had multiple items, would it still work the same? Select price, code, sku from table 1 union all select price, code, sku from table2 WHERE code='blah'?  Sorry, just realized i need the where in there a well to do a where on both tables

Comment: @Damien Of course you can, you have to test it.